# Realtime Transmit Recorded Audio using RTP on websocket - Javascript and WEBRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, audio-recording

I am new to webRTC. I want to record audio from browser and then send raw audio into RTP  over WebSocket to another machine that in my local network.

1. How Do I form this RTP packets ?
2. Is is possible to stream this packets to remote machine/server while recording  ?

I am using [RECORD RTC](https://recordrtc.org/RecordRTC.html).
Here is my Code  :

```
  const player = document.getElementById('player');

    const handleSuccess = function(stream) {


    const context = new AudioContext();
    var channels = 2;
    const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 2, 1);


    var buffer = context.createBuffer(2, 22050, 44100);
    var frameCount = context.sampleRate * 2.0;
    var myArrayBuffer = context.createBuffer(2, frameCount, context.sampleRate);

    console.log("My Array buffer " , myArrayBuffer );

    source.connect(processor);
    processor.connect(context.destination);


    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
      // Do something with the data, e.g. convert it to WAV
      console.log(e.inputBuffer);
    }; 

    if (window.URL) {
      player.srcObject = stream;
       console.log("Stream is  "  , stream.toString());
    } else {
      player.src = stream;

      console.log("Stream is  "  , stream.toString());
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
      .then(handleSuccess);


  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
    devices = devices.filter((d) => d.kind === 'audioinput');
    console.log("Devices are  " , devices);     
});
```

The code allows me to stream audio , I just want to send the recorded stream, in RAW format using RTP protocol.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Julian I have not.

Comment: thanks for the response. We'll be circling back around to audio in the next coming weeks, but I found some success with a backchannel library at https://github.com/mbullington/yellowstone - direct stream from browser into the rtp stream may be complicated but we're considering setting a UI that the user holds a button to collect mic data, and on release we collect the stream and format a ulaw wav file and transmit that over... not exactly what you/we're looking for but a step in the right direction. Will update if we find anything different.

Comment: so webrtc -> node server via websocket, format mic data on button release -> rtsp via yellowstone. hope this sparks an idea or something lol